# Can the Hold Person spell target an Eladrin NPC?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, eladrin

In D&D 5th edition, can the *Hold Person* spell affect an Eladrin NPC?

The [*Hold Person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hold-person) spell specifically targets "humanoids". Meanwhile, the (NPC/monster) stat blocks for [Eladrin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/motm/bestiary-ek#Eladrin) say that they are officially classified as "Fey (elf)". Fey is a fey, and Elf is a humanoid.

I saw that someone posted somewhere:

> Elf is a tag, not a creature type. Eladrin are elves that have not yet lost their fey nature. Humanoid elves are elves that have.

I just wanted to verify the official rules.

Comment: I think you should clarify that you are talking about the monster eladrin, not the PC eladrin. The monster eladrin is a Fey, but the PC eladrin is a Humanoid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Tags have no rules of their own.

From the [Introduction to the *Monster Manual*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#Tags) (or the [corresponding part of the Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Tags)):

> The parenthetical tags provide additional categorization for certain creatures. The tags have no rules of their own, but something in the game, such as a magic item, might refer to them.

Therefore, tags have no effect on the creature's Type. The Elf tag does not indicate humanoid or fey, it is merely a category marker.

So, no, *hold person* does not affect Eladrin since they do not have the Type of Humanoid.